# How to declare a variable but not assign it?

Tags: rust, initialization

I want to declare `acceptable_set` and use it. But an empty vector is assigned to it. So the compiler warns. How to declare a variable and do not assign it?

```rust
let mut acceptable_set: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
if opt.acceptable_set.is_none() {
    acceptable_set = crate::builtin_words::ACCEPTABLE
        .to_vec()
        .iter_mut()
        .map(|x| x.to_string())
        .collect();
} else {
    acceptable_set = get_acceptable_set(opt)
}
```

```text
warning: value assigned to `acceptable_set` is never read
  --> src/basic_function.rs:27:13
   |
27 |     let mut acceptable_set: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_assignments)]` on by default
   = help: maybe it is overwritten before being read?
```

Comment: just use `;` after the name of the variable (or eventually its type annotation), but don't use `=`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of declaring an uninitialised variable like this

```rust
let var;
if condition {
  var = value1;
} else {
  var = value2;
}
```

you could [directly initialise](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html#using-if-in-a-let-statement) the variable with the alternative.

```rust
let var = if condition { value1 } else { value2 };
```

Your variable does not even need the `mut` keyword (except if you want to mutate it afterwards).

And since in the example of your question you seem to test against an `Option` (`.is_none()`), you could use this form.

```rust
fn main() {
    let value1 = 12;
    let value2 = 34;
    let opt = Some(987);
    let var = if let Some(opt_value) = opt {
        value1 + opt_value // use the data in the option
    } else {
        value2 // the option contains nothing, use a default value
    };
    println!("var {:?}", var);
}
```

See also [map_or_else()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or_else).

Comment: I would recommend to directly initialize the variable rather than declaring it, as it's much more readable.